# The type XXX is not assignable to service YYY

Tags: c#, autofac

I need help with my autofac generics configuration. I get the below error which I can't seem to get around. I have an interface using generics called `IScript<TOptionType>`.

Implementing that interface is an abstract class called `Script<TOptionType> : IScript<TOptionType>`. Derived from that abstract class are two concrete classes that set their preferred `TOptionType`.

I've uploaded a sample .net core application that exhibits the problem here: https://github.com/Strandedpirate/agr

To run go to `agr\autofac-generic-registration` and type in `dotnet run`.

C# seems to have no problems boxing the concrete types to either the interface or abstract base class. So why is autofac complaining here?

```
C:\Users\strandedpirate\source\repos\agr\autofac-generic-registration (master -> origin)
λ dotnet run

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The type 'agr.TableScript' is not assignable to service 'agr.Script`1'.
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration(Guid id, RegistrationData data, IInstanceActivator activator, Service[] services, IComponentRegistration target) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Builder\RegistrationBuilder.cs:line 192
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration[TLimit,TActivatorData,TSingleRegistrationStyle](IRegistrationBuilder`3 builder) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Builder\RegistrationBuilder.cs:line 132
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.RegisterSingleComponent[TLimit,TActivatorData,TSingleRegistrationStyle](IComponentRegistry cr, IRegistrationBuilder`3 builder) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Builder\RegistrationBuilder.cs:line 249
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ContainerBuilder.cs:line 240
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ContainerBuilder.cs:line 148
   at agr.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\strandedpirate\source\repos\agr\autofac-generic-registration\Program.cs:line 22
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // comment out the next registrations to see the program run.
            builder.RegisterType<TableScript>()
              .As<Script<TableScriptOptions>>()
              .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<TableScript>()
              .As(typeof(Script<>))
              .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<TableScript>()
              .As(typeof(IScript<>))
              .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // explodes here during autofac building.
            var container = builder.Build();

            // if you comment out the above autofac configuration this will succeed compile and run-time.
            // why does c# have no problems converting TableScript to IScript<T> and Script<T> but autofac is complaining?
            TestInterface(new TableScript());
            TestAbstractBase(new TableScript());

            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Resolving IScript instance...");
                var instance = scope.Resolve(typeof(IScript<>)) as IScript<object>;
                instance.Run();
            }
        }

        static void TestInterface<T>(IScript<T> a)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(TestInterface)} called - {a.CanHandle("table")}");
        }

        static void TestAbstractBase<T>(Script<T> a)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(TestAbstractBase)} called - {a.CanHandle("table")}");
        }
    }
```

**IScript.cs**

```
public interface IScript<TOptionType>
        where TOptionType : class, new()
    {
        bool CanHandle(string key);
        Task Run();
        bool Validate(TOptionType options);
    }
```

**Script.cs**

```
public abstract class Script<TOptionType> : IScript<TOptionType>
        where TOptionType : class, new()
    {
        public abstract bool CanHandle(string key);

        public abstract Task Run();

        public virtual bool Validate(TOptionType options)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**TableScript.cs**

```
    public class TableScript : Script<TableScriptOptions>
    {
        public override bool CanHandle(string key)
        {
            return key == "table";
        }

        public override Task Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(TableScript)} executed");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**FileScript.cs**

```
    public class FileScript : Script<FileScriptOptions>
    {
        public override bool CanHandle(string key)
        {
            return key == "file";
        }

        public override Task Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(FileScript)} executed");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really sure what should happen (or what you expect to happen) when you try to register specific type as open generic (`.As(typeof(IScript<>))` )... but that looks *very* suspicious  to me.

Comment: Side note: there is no way to "box" classes - "boxing the concrete types" - boxing is only defined for value types. You probably mean something else there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

First, your `TableScript` registration:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<TableScript>()
       .As(typeof(Script<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<TableScript>()
       .As(typeof(IScript<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You're trying to register a *closed generic* as an *open generic*. If you think about what that means, it'd be like saying "`TableScript` can allow *any `T`* for `Script<T>` and `IScript<T>`". For example, I see `TableScript : Script<TableScriptOptions>` - what the open generic registration is saying is it should somehow also work for `Script<IntegerScriptOptions>` or anything else that could possibly go inside those angle brackets.

Instead, register it as the closed generic it is. And I would recommend doing it on the same registration or you could get two *different instances* of `TableScript` per lifetime scope depending on which service gets resolved.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<TableScript>()
       .As<Script<TableScriptOptions>>()
       .As<IScript<TableScriptOptions>>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Next, the resolution of `IScript<T>`:

```cs
scope.Resolve(typeof(IScript<>)) as IScript<object>;
```

Think of `Resolve` as being a lot like `new`. If you can't use `new` or `Activator.CreateInstance` in its place (basically) then it won't work. For example, you can't do this:

```cs
// This isn't a thing
new Script<>();
```

You also can't put an open generic into a constructor of an object quite like this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
  // This also isn't a thing
  public MyClass(IScript<> script) { /* ... */ }
}
```

You can't new-up an open generic. The compiler needs to know what the `T` is in `Script<T>`. By that same token, you can't resolve an open generic. That doesn't make sense. You have to resolve a closed generic.

```cs
scope.Resolve<IScript<TableScriptOptions>>();
```

If you really want to use reflection, you still have to make it a closed generic.

```cs
var script = typeof(IScript<>);
var options = typeof(TableScriptOptions);
var closed = script.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { options });
scope.Resolve(closed);
```

Comment: Excellent, those details got me to the finish line.